# jquery inside document.ready alert for all event accurance like click,load,change,resize,scroll,etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

i need an alert inside document.ready which need to pop in all event accurances
like click mouseenter mouseout drag scroll focus blur resize etc.. and all
any comments are welcome 
thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/*for every event*/
  alert();
});
```

like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this for all events.

```js
function triggerAllEvents(el) {
    var resultArray = [];
    for (var key in el) {
        if (key.indexOf('on') === 0) {
            resultArray.push(key.slice(2));
        }
    }
    return resultArray.join(' ');
}

var element = $('#some-el');
element.bind(triggerAllEvents(element[0]), function(e) {
    alert("hello");
});
```